# AJAX: request.status == 200 returning false? (data not displaying on page)

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

So I am trying to create a simple ajax request that returns hello world text from data.txt (in same root directory).

> PROBLEM: When checking the status === 200 if statement doesn't display
>   anything i.e. its not returning true.
>
> TWIST: But if the if statement is removed the request is logged onto
>   the console (but the data is not being written on the page.

CODE

```
// AJAX REQUEST EXAMPLE
// XHR is the api that is used for AJAX REQUESTS
// Create a XHR request object

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
// create the 'request' for this object. open() reqest method GET/POST, location of the data file (ajax requests has same domain poilcy - so you can't request data objects for domains from other than what your currently on), true/fasle (whether we want request ot be asyncronous or not fasle means its asyc i.e. brwoser waits until requests is done before it does anything else )
request.open('GET', 'data.txt', true);
// send request to the server for data
request.send();
if (request.status=== 200) {
  document.writeln(request.responseText);

 }
    console.log(request);
```

Comment: it's not clear .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope that this will help you to understand, I have placed some comments for you. Feel free to ask me everything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>stackoverflow test</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // AJAX REQUEST EXAMPLE
    // XHR is the api that is used for AJAX REQUESTS
    // Create a XHR request object

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();


    request.onreadystatechange = function() //This is to wait for response (eventually from your PHP script)
    {
      if (request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200) //And when status is OK use result
      {

        document.writeln(request.responseText);
        console.log(request.status); //here the status request
        console.log(request); //here the complete object request
      }
    }

    // open() request method GET/POST, location of the data file (ajax requests has same domain policy - so you can't request data objects for domains from other than what your currently on), true/false (whether we want request ot be asyncronous or not false means its asyc i.e. browser waits until requests is done before it does anything else )
    request.open('GET', 'data.txt', true);
    // send request to the server for data
    request.send();


  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Now you will get `200` as `success request` in browser console, and the `data.txt` output in the browser.

[image: stack_example]

Cheers, Giulio

Comment: Okay your code works: 2 Questions: apart from checking request.readyState === 4 and adding onreadystatechange () the code isn't much different, then why doesn't my code work? ideas :)

Comment: Question 2: onreadystatechange  is it required, and what is its purpose with php?

Comment: Trying to figure out what I am fundamentally doing wrong here so as to not repeat it ;)

Comment: @Shaz the question 1 -> one of the main reasons that causes the wrong execution of your code is related to the fact that you don't have `onReadyStateChange` event listener. In fact this listener is really useful especially in AJAX for verify if an element was correctly loaded and if the loading state of an element has changed or not.  Question 2 -> the purpose with **PHP** is for make an external (and absolutely more secure) additional control of your request with `$_SESSION["Status"] === "200"]` for example. Let me know if my explanation is clear :-)

Answer (score 0):

200 mean success

Check here :
https://support.oneskyapp.com/hc/en-us/articles/222410047-What-are-those-API-status-code-e-g-200-201-400-503-

Comment: I know, but by removing the if statement entirely i get the request object shown in my console by doesn't display text in browser